# How to change Rails params when trying to edit multiple records at a time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to change the params that the form pass from the controller. For example, the form will have a check box. The check box pass the values 0 or 1. I need to convert them into true and false before submitting. There are some values like that I need to change.

But Im trying to update multiple records in the same page like in this tutorial : http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised. In this situation, how to change the params?

My controller :

```
def update_submits
    @submits = Submit.update(params[:submits].keys, params[:submits].values)

    if @submits.empty?
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        @rejected = current_user.rejected
        render 'uploaded'
    end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the value_methods on the checkboxes on the form?

Comment: You mean this ?? `params[:key] = new_value` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need convert `0` to `false`? look example and you understand what i mean:

```
=> Record.last
#> Record Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"   ORDER BY "records"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Record id: 1, private: false ....>
=> Record.last.update(private: 1)
#> Record Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"   ORDER BY "records"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
#> (1.3ms)  BEGIN
#> ........
#> SQL (4.4ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "private" = $1 WHERE "records"."id" = '1'  [["private", "t"]]
#> true
=> Record.last
=> #<Record id: 1, private: true ....>
```

Rails have set of [`values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e595d91ac2c07371b441f8b04781e7c03ac44135/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb#L8) for work this db columns:

```
TRUE_VALUES = [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE', 'on', 'ON'].to_set
FALSE_VALUES = [false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE', 'off', 'OFF'].to_set
```

This mean that you can pass as `false` to `update()` any  value form this list `false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE', 'off', 'OFF'`

And after all (not sure if this need now). how change `params` before pass to update (simple way this `tap()`):

```
def record_params
  params.permit(:name, :last_name).tap do |record_params|
    record_params[:some_attribut] = true
  end
end
```

This return updated `params`.